# How to write Windows registry while installing MSI package written in Kotlin Compose for desktop?

Tags: kotlin

I'm getting stuck at trying to write the windows registry entries while installing the MSI package which is written in Kotlin Compose for desktop. Anyone can share experiences please? Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Cyclonecode We looked around on google but didn't see any way to do it.